# My h1 not appearing after adding my navigation bar and background-color

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

- Hello, after adding my navigation bar in background-color my h1 is
  not showing up. I'm trying to center my h1-h6 tag in the center of my
  website so I can style it to a different font type but when I add my
  h1 tag with the , , or  the h1 tag still doesn't
  appear.

```html
<!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <!---Font Awesome-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e093169393.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!---Google Fonts-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css"/>
    
    
    
    <!---CSS Stylesheets-->
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/all.min.css">
    
    <!---Font Awesome-->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>
    
    <!--Bootstrap Script-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></<>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    
    <!---ICON--->
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    
    
    <!---NAVBAR MENU-->
    <html>
        <head>
            <body>
                <h1>HERES MY H1</h1>
            </body>
        </head>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        </html>
    
    <!---About Me --->
    
    < !----Toggle--->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    
    
    < !----Icon Widgets--->
    
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item>
                  <form>
                    <label for="search class="search bar></label>
                    </form>
                    <a class="nav-link" href=""><input type="text" placeholder="Search"></a>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-bag-shopping"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </nav>
    
    <!---SHOPPING ICON--->
```

Comment: I do not see where you are adding any h1 tags in your html. Please check your code as I think you missed it.
Also not sure what you mean by **but when I add my h1 tag with the , , or the h1 tag still doesn't appear.**

Comment: @deemyBoy After placing my navbar and logo to the center of my navigation bar, I want to add a h1 tag inside of my code so I may center my h1 tag in the middle of my website. However, when I try to have the h1 tag, nothing appears.

Comment: But my comment said your code was missing - please update your code. I understand what you want to do but need to see **how** you are doing it

Comment: @deemyBoy I just update my code

Comment: you have not changed any of the HTML - I still cannot see any <h1> tags anywhere. I'm expecting to see something like `<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="/docs/4.3/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
          Bootstrap
        </a>
      </nav>
      <h1>This is my heading that I cannot see</h1>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: @deemyBoy I just updated my code I put my h1 where is says navigation menu

Comment: also looks like your trying to put a form inside a navbar do you want a "search" type input that a lot of websites these days are putting at the top of the page.         `<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
             <li class="nav-item>
           <form>
             <label for="search" class="search-bar"></label>
             
             <a class="nav-link" href=""><input type="text" placeholder="Search"></a></form>
             <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-bag-shopping"></i></a>
             </li>
         </ul>
     </div>`

Comment: @deemyBoy yes I do

Comment: some of your code was missing quotes so I added them and I surrounded you input inside the form because that's where inputs usually go. Look at [form basics](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_forms.htm)

Comment: @deemyBoy thank you and how about the h1 tag?

Answer (score 1):

I think your trying to run before you can walk. It's good to learn new things but step by step.

First try to understand what a webpage is and how it's made.

Try to understand The DOM [DOM basics](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/dom-explained-everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-document-object-model/)

Then the different tags (div, span, p, h1, h2, h3, em, style, script, head, body, html)

Then navigation using <a href="some-website-address.com">Cool Website Dude!</>

Forms are VERY hard for a beginner as they involve more than just front-end code (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) as now you're writing back-end code that talks to the server and a database if you have one!

Basics first, then more complicated topics.

I have updated your code but not sure if it will give you what you want.

**You only have 1 pair of html, head and body tags in a webpage btw.**

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
            <!---Font Awesome-->
            <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e093169393.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <!---Google Fonts-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css"/>
    
    
    
            <!---CSS Stylesheets-->
            <!-- CSS only -->
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/all.min.css">
    
            <!---Font Awesome-->
            <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>
    
            <!--Bootstrap Script-->
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></<>
                <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item>
                        <form>
                            <label for="search" class="search-bar"></label>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="">
                                <input name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                            </a>
                        </form>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-bag-shopping"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <h1>HERES MY H1</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
```